# How evaluating $\int_0^2 f(x)dx$ from $\int_2^3 f(x)dx$ and $\int_1^2xf(x^2-1)dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form

I have two results:

$\int_2^3f(x)dx=5$

and

$\int_1^2 xf(x^2-1)dx=8$

I need to calculate:
$$\int_0^2 f(x)dx$$

I have no idea about using the previous results, any hint?

Comment: There's an obvious change of variables to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. One may perform a change of variable, $u=x^2-1$, $du=2xdx$, giving
$$
\int_1^2 xf(x^2-1)dx=\frac12\int_1^2 2xf(x^2-1)dx=\frac12\int_0^3 f(u)du=8
$$ then one may write
$$
\int_0^2 f(x)dx=\int_0^3 f(x)dx+\int_3^2 f(x)dx=\int_0^3 f(x)dx-\int_2^3 f(x)dx
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I understand but i'm not sure about the result, it's $4-5=-1$ ?

Comment: @Marco It's rather $16-5=11$, isn't it?

Comment: Why 16? isn't $\frac{1}{2} 8$ ?

Comment: We have $\frac12\int_0^3 f(u)du=8$ giving $\int_0^3 f(u)du=2\times8=16.$